# Meditation practice - Meditation Odd Effect -

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities, meditation-effects

I am doing vipassana meditation from last six month and had done two 10 days course  of S N Goenka Vipassana Meditation.Doing daily 2 hours meditation in morning and evening. I am having constant sensation on my right cheek and on forehead during meditation and even after meditation almost 24 hours.

Also have continure sensation  in head in brain, on top, Side and back side of head ,I am not able to sleep due to it and  I am feeling i am doing some thing wrong. As i understand that i am not monk who engage in meditation 24 hours. Should i do simple anapana, Not vipassana ? What should i do ? How can overcome it ? Or I should leave meditation and leave life as earlier as i was living ?

Kindly provide solution in detail how to do, Like do it yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Should I do simple anapana, Not vipassana?**

Spend 1/3 time in Anapana and 2/3 time in Vipassana. If you are doing a 1-hour session to about 10 to 20 minutes of Anapana and then Vipassana.

> **How can overcome it?**

When you are doing mediation different sesations surcafes due to past conditioning and perceptions surfacing. People experience different sensations like tingling, falling, inflating, deflating, floating, burning, frightening images, please images, traumatic memories of the past, etc. The objective of meditation is to train one's mind to be equanimous to them and face them. So do not get averse, or worried about that you are experiencing and be equanimous about it and continue your practice.

Answer (score 1):

I know how you feel. I'll give you a couple of personal examples and how I was advised by my teaching monks and got past these kind of experiences. (I also practice Vipassana)

Once I was on retreat in Lumbini, and as the retreat went on, my heartbeat kept getting louder and louder. Soon, it was so bad I couldn't focus on my breath or body at all, just this constant annoying heartbeat! It was unbearable! I just wanted to meditate in peace with my pleasant breath. I wished this heartbeat sensation would just stop. I started feeling anxious about it, and started making theories about how to solve my external problems. It must be the coffee I thought.

I went to report to my teaching monk all of this. He smiled, and said "Oh, don't feel bad about your heart! It does such good regular work for you, keeping you alive. Invite this heartbeat in for tea and biscuits, be friends with it. Observe the heartbeat just like the breath. Know when it changes, observe what conditions this awareness of the heart to arise, and to pass."

On another retreat, at the TMC in San Jose, we had a beautiful and silent meditation hall. A few days into my personal retreat, the monk told us they needed to remodel, and meditation would be held in a different smaller room, just some small space for a few cushions, table, and a clock on the wall. Well, soon enough that clock began to seem really loud. I would begin fantasizing about taking it down, or dream of talking to the staff about it "how could you place such a loud clock in a meditation room!" I'd want to say. My heartbeat and breath began syncing and getting in rhythm with the clock. It began to be a struggle, and I felt I had to constantly control my breath and heart.

In the next reporting session with the monk, I brought up the evil clock. The monk said "The clock is not problem. The problem is inside the mind."

In both these circumstances, there was a sensation that was felt to be negative. There was a resistance to them, thinking of this thing as something to get rid of, to control or change. I over focused on them, getting worked up and anxious over them, which spiraled to become worse everyday. That is, until I began to invite them in. I allowed myself to experience them completely, without trying to change them. I practiced Equanimity - it doesn't come immediately, but when you feel disliking, be aware that you are, and soften it, accepting. Know when the disliking arises, and observe it just like anything else.

Soon, when the clock or the heartbeat are no longer identified as an enemy, you begin to find pleasant feelings there too. You begin to have less and less aversion. Soon, the heartbeat or clock are just momentary friends stopping by for a quick chat, and then one goes back to the primary object, feeling even more peace and Equanimity. You'll find you have progressed, and new experiences trouble you less and less. Its all a series of friends stopping by. Just be mindful enough to know when they are coming through your door.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that these experiences are not as a result of meditation but when you are in meditaion you are more tune with the body and surrounding so you are more aware of the things that always there. 
However, you also see other meditative experiences such as Pithi and Sukha.

Answer (score 0):

people who report on their vipassana mediation invented by all those teacher like Mahazi GOenka and so on  always report some areas with weird tingling, vibrations, buzzes and so on. They also add that those weird and annoying vibrations disappear once they stop whatever wrong samadhi they have been taught.
THe most important thing you must do is not panicking over this and stop doing it.